# Django CMS Apphook - no app content is shown on page

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I integrated an app into the cms using the documentation. All ist set but the CMS doesnt show the app content. It seems base.html will not show the content of my app.

Could it be my app-used template ?

```
list.html
    {% extends CMS_TEMPLATE %}
    {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
    {% load cms_tags sekizai_tags staticfiles  %}

    {% block main %}

        {% addtoblock "css" %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "django_tables2/themes/paleblue/css/screen.css"%}">{% endaddtoblock %}
        {% render_table doctor_htmltable %}

    {% endblock main %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. although I still do not find it mentioned anywhere in the documentation.

In my base.html a block is defined:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

and so everything the app should display must also be include into a block with the same name

```
{% block content %}
   ....(see lines in question)
{% endblock content %}
```